# Why does my crispy form not load until I click the View Image/View PDF button?

Tags: django, web, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

[image: When I load the page it looks like this]

Upon loading, it looks like the image above. In the middle, there is an upload file form done through crispyforms.

[image: I want the page to look like this]

This is how I want it to look like upon loading the website. Instead, I need to click a button before this upload part of the form shows up.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" >tul.ai</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button name = "upload_image" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">View Image</button>
        <button name = "upload_pdf" class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">View PDF</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Above is the HTML with the crispyform.

from django import forms
from .models import Photo, PDF

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['image']

class PDFForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # file = forms.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = PDF
        fields =  ['file']
```

Above is the code for the forms themselves.

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='imgs')
    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if self.image.height > 2200 or self.image.width > 1700:
            output_size = (1700, 2200)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path, quality = 100)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'photo'



class PDF(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs')
    def save(self):
        super().save()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'pdf'
```

This is the models.py file.